# Error compiling Apache with SSL on RHEL 6.10

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, openssl, rhel

I'm trying to compile Apache on RHEL 6.10
Requirements are: no root access and use native RHEL OpenSSL

openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

but when I try to ./configure Apache 2.4.39 with

> ... --prefix=/sb/sys1/apache
>   --with-ssl=/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/include/openssl ... --enable-ssl --enable-so

it brings SSL related errors:

```
checking whether to enable mod_ssl... checking dependencies
checking for OpenSSL... checking for user-provided OpenSSL base directory... /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/include/openssl
  adding "-I/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/include/openssl/include" to CPPFLAGS
  setting MOD_CFLAGS to "-I/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/include/openssl/include"
  setting ab_CFLAGS to "-I/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/include/openssl/include"
  adding "-L/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/include/openssl/lib" to LDFLAGS
  setting MOD_LDFLAGS to "-L/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/include/openssl/lib"
checking for OpenSSL version >= 0.9.8a... FAILED
  adding "-lssl" to MOD_LDFLAGS
  adding "-lcrypto" to MOD_LDFLAGS
  adding "-lrt" to MOD_LDFLAGS
  adding "-lcrypt" to MOD_LDFLAGS
  adding "-lpthread" to MOD_LDFLAGS
  setting LIBS to "-lssl -lcrypto  -lrt -lcrypt  -lpthread"
  forcing ab_LIBS to "-L/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/include/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread"
checking openssl/engine.h usability... no
checking openssl/engine.h presence... no
checking for openssl/engine.h... no
checking for SSL_CTX_new... no
checking for ENGINE_init... no
checking for ENGINE_load_builtin_engines... no
checking for RAND_egd... no
configure: WARNING: OpenSSL libraries are unusable
yes
```

Any ideas why Apache doesn't seem to accept OpenSSL, while the version looks ok?

Comment: RHEL 6.10 : The default ssl is `openssl-1.0.1e`. .... Why do you want to use an old version ? .... 1.0.1e : `# yum install openssl-devel` .... Hints : httpd-2.4.39 build file → https://www.dropbox.com/s/ba6djdmo60r6dzh/httpd-2.4.39.spec.txt?dl=0 ... See configure text ... and patches.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own root for the server. So there's no way to use the current version?

Comment: Current is `openssl-devel-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64`. Unpack openssl-devel-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64.tar.gz in /home/[ *name* /], and you get `/home/name/{include/, lib/}` "all openssl files". Link to the new local "-devel package" = https://www.dropbox.com/s/19tpf76gke0svuo/openssl-devel-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64.tar.gz?dl=0